# Giving a user a 'primary key' inside their data domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have a rails app that consists of lots of accounts.

Inside these accounts users can create tickets.

What is the best way to give each ticket a Id that is sequential inside their account?

Obviously managing the id's myself seems to be the initial answer, but this seems to be filled with all sort of edge cases that would cause issues (for instance, two tickets writing down to the DB at once...)

Comment: Why do you want tickets to have IDs scoped under each account? Also, are there fields unique to a ticket that you can use instead of ID?

Comment: Yes, IDs scoped under an account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll end up managing them yourself - I've implemented something similar previously, account stored 'current_ticket_id' and then when a ticket (for example) get's created it is still stored with a global PK but then an observer assigns it a friendly_ticket_id and then increments to one on the account model for the next time round. You can use the friendly_ticket_id scoped to the account via your URLs to make sure you get the right ticket back.